# Problem with Predicates in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, delegates, predicates

I have the following method definition (EDITED to remove redundant generic):

```
public static T SearchAgaistValues<T>(Dictionary<string, string> input, 
string key, List<T> values, Predicate<T> match, out string[] cmdParams)
```

My simplified requirements are as follows. I need to search `input` for `key`, and if found, see if its value appears in `values`. However, `values` is generic (and will obviously contain a string that I need to match). Therefore, the way I see it, I have to pass a predicate method to perform the matching.

However, every example of `Predicate<T>` I have seen has a hard coded comparitor. I need to compare the found `key's` value to each item in `values`. I cannot pass these values, however.

I can't see how to do this outside of a foreach loop with a delegate based match method.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What's the point of the type parameter T here?

Comment: Also, if `values` is a generic list, but will contain a string that you need to match, do you mean that you need to match a string property of the objects in `values`, or what? Please clarify.

Comment: " However, values is generic (and will obviously contain a string that I need to match)." I need to match exactly what you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see it you have two options, without changing crazy requirements.

Option 1 is to use `Func<string, T1, bool>` instead of `Predicate<T1>`.  This way the predicate can convert between string and T1 as needed and return the boolean matched result.

```
public static T1 SearchAgaistValues<T, T1>(
            Dictionary<string, string> input, 
            string key, 
            List<T1> values, 
            Func<string, T1, bool> match, 
            out string[] cmdParams)
```

Alternatively you can pass an additional `Converter<T1, string>` parameter to convert the looked-up string to a T1 and then compare using the predicate.

```
public static T1 SearchAgaistValues<T, T1>(
            Dictionary<string, string> input, 
            string key, 
            List<T1> values, 
            Converter<T1, string> converter,
            Predicate<T1> match, 
            out string[] cmdParams)
```

Both cases are less than ideal though.  This function sounds a lot more like a problem looking for a solution than the other way around.  The signature is a bit crazy and seems like it can be greatly simplified by restating the requirements or breaking it up into pieces.

Comment: It started off innocently, but got a bit complex, then grew into wanting to learn how to do it properly. Perhaps it would be better to be less generic in this case.